# How to make login in django via login/pass from database?

Tags: django, authentication

There is a table 'user' in db which has an attributes 'login', 'password' 'name' and others.
How should i make login page? Passwords stored in non-encrypted type (just '1234')
(1) I tried this:

```
def check_login_password(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    if request.POST:
        login = request.POST.get('login','')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')
        user = auth.authenticate(username=login, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('/test')
        else:
            args['login_error']="User not found!"
            return render(request, 'registration/login.html', args)
    else:
        return render(request, 'registration/login.html', args)
```

But this function does not see users in db (user is always none), i only could login via superuser login/pass.

(2) I tried use included Django authentication method with abstract user model:
`path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'), name='login'),` - urls.py

But it doesn't work too.

Hope, you will help me make login page.

Comment: How about using the [LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.